# How to change bar color at a specific value with Apex Charts?

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

Is there a way to change the color of a bar on Apex charts below a specific value? For example when a weight above 200 lbs the bar changes red.

Here is the code I am working with but I am not quite sure what I am supposed to put for value, seriesIndex, and w

```
colors: ['#02DFDE'],
             fill: {
                 colors: [function({ value, seriesIndex, w }) {
                    if(value < 360) {
                      return '#FF0000'
                  } else {
                      return '#02DFDE'
                  }
                }]
         },
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to set the color based on value, then this function will suffice

```js
colors: [
  function({ value, seriesIndex, w }) {
    if (value < 5000) {
      return '#FF0000'
    } else {
      return '#02DFDE'
    }
  }
]
```

Full example - https://codepen.io/apexcharts/pen/RwRNXzX?editors=0010
[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you :)

Comment: I knew it, but how about whole of series in same condition??
Because I have much of series up to 480 series bar

Comment: Will this work on a line chart?

Comment: @junedchhipa can I change the color on bar in opposite direction? question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78215768/apexcharts-how-to-use-different-color-on-opposite-bar-chart-begin-on-specified-v