# Apexcharts How to use different color on opposite bar chart begin on specified value (not zero)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apex, apexcharts

How to use different color on opposite bar chart begin on specified value (not zero).

I already explore the Apexcharts docs example and can't found any similar approach for my need, all example always use zero value as an axis.

[image]

The above example use `0` value as the axis to begin the different bar color with this yaxis

```
yaxis: {
          min: -100,
          max: 100,
       }
```

What I want is to use `50` value as the axis in this y-axis

```
yaxis: {
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
       }

series: [
    {
        name: 'title1',
        data: [80, 20]
    }
],
```

All codes

```
new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components: {
          apexchart: VueApexCharts,
        },
        data: {
            series: [
                {
                    name: 'title1',
                    data: [80, 20]
                }
            ],
            chartOptions: {
                chart: {
                  type: 'bar',
                  height: 350
                },
                xaxis: {
                  categories: ['South Korea'
                  ],
                },
                yaxis: {
                  min: 0,
                  max: 100,
                },
                plotOptions: {
                  bar: {
                    borderRadius: 4,
                    borderRadiusApplication: 'end',
                    horizontal: false,
                  }
                },
                dataLabels: {
                  enabled: false
                },
            },
        },
        
    })
```

Comment: For clarification: Is your goal that the right bar stays as it is and that the left one has e.g. a color green from 0 to 50 and blue from 50 to 60? Also your code does not match the screenshot.

Comment: @jan sorry It should come from the same/single data series. The code is what I try to achieve. the screenshot code using negative yaxis ````yaxis: {min: -100,max: 100, },```` and the data should single data only ````series: [{  name: 'title1', data: [80, 20] },````

Comment: So do you want to have only one bar in the result if there shall only be one series? Shall it look like in the screenshot? There are two series.

Comment: @jan the real data has a lot of data paired with datetime as xaxis.

Comment: Yes, but I still don't get how the expected output shall look like. You mention one series in the comment but the screenshot above shows two series.

Comment: @jan it should work with one series with negative yaxis.. I have edit the question. reference https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/bar-charts/bar-with-negative-values/